# How to make a proper binding adapter for 2 way data binding in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I am attempting to make a page in my Android app that allows the user to enter a Float value in an EditText and binds that value to my view model. Here is my code for my current binding adapter:

```
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import androidx.databinding.InverseBindingAdapter

@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun setText(view: EditText, value: Float?) {
    view.text = value?.let { SpannableStringBuilder(value.toString()) } ?: SpannableStringBuilder("")
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text", event = "android:textAttrChanged")
fun getTextString(view: EditText): Float? {
    val editTextString: String? = view.text?.toString()
    return if(editTextString == null || editTextString == "") 0.0f else editTextString.toString().toFloat()
}
```

Here is the code that I have for my EditText in my layout file:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/amount_edit_text_outer"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edit_text_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/amount_edit_text_inner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@={viewmodel.liveAmount$app_debug}"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Finally, my view model live data variable looks like this:

```
internal val liveAmount = MutableLiveData<Float>(0.0f)
```

I should also add that when I run this code on my phone, it allows me to enter the first number in the EditText and nothing else. Furthermore, the keyboard does not go away unless I kill the app. Any questions or comments are welcome. Thank you all for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text", event = "android:textAttrChanged")
```

to:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
```

And add this other method:

```
// This notifies the data binding system that the attribute value has changed.
@BindingAdapter("android:textAttrChanged")
fun setTextChangedListener(editText: TextInputEditText, listener: InverseBindingListener) {
    editText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            listener.onChange()
        }
    })
}
```

This is not tested, but it should work or at least be close. See here for other similar examples:

https://github.com/gavingt/upcoming-games/blob/adc8b7e67b1e05d7bc9ac6247b82cfa93a43a26f/app/src/main/java/com/gavinsappcreations/upcominggames/utilities/BindingAdapters.kt#L324

Comment: Do the overridden functions have to be filled in? If so what kind of code would I put in them? I've read the documentation for TextWatcher but I can't get a grip on exactly what it does

Comment: TextWatcher enables callbacks in EditTexts for whenever the text changes. So `afterTextChanged()` gets called after every character the user types into the EditText. Usually you don't need `beforeTextChanged()` and `onTextChanged()`. And you can just leave them blank.

Comment: And at which point is the listener removed (memory management)?

Comment: I don't think you bother removing listeners from `Views`. You wouldn't remove an `OnClickListener`, for instance. Its lifecycle is just tied to the `View`.

Comment: I just found out, that [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) suggest to use `androidx.databinding.adapters.ListenerUtil` to track the listener created inside binding method. You should later use `ListenerUtil` to correctly unregister the listener to avoid memory leaks. More complex examples can be found in Android default bindings ([example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/refs/heads/studio-master-dev/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/androidx/databinding/adapters/TextViewBindingAdapter.java#352))

Comment: I'm sorry, the `ListenerUtil` is a bit confusing. I just realized that that's only useful when your component supports multiple listeners. So you are absolutely right: there is no need to bother removing listener for adapters which register only a **one/single listener**.